Generated PDF From images in dart with pdf pub Package gets corrupted
I'm trying to generate a pdf with a list of images, and each image gets added to a new page inside the pdf. the issue is it gets created but the pdf is corrupted.
I'm using pdf pub package and path provider to generate and save it on the device
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';


Future<File> generatePDFDoc(List<File> croppedImageList) async {
    try {
      final pdf = pw.Document();

      final List imageDataList = [];

      croppedImageList.forEach((singleImage) {
        final image = pw.MemoryImage(
          singleImage.readAsBytesSync(),
        );

        imageDataList.add(image);
      });

      if (imageDataList.length > 0) {
        // images are added on to list
        // now add them to pages
        imageDataList.forEach((imageFile) {
          pdf.addPage(pw.Page(build: (pw.Context context) {
            return pw.Center(
              child: pw.Image(imageFile),
            ); // Center
          })); // Page // Page
        });
      }

      var status = await Permission.storage.status;

      if (!status.isGranted) {
        await Permission.storage.request();
      }

      Directory dir = Directory('');

      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        // dir = Directory("/storage/emulated/0/Download");
        dir = (await getDownloadsDirectory())!;
      } else {
        dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      }

      final file = new File("${dir.path}/document.pdf");
      final compFile = await file.writeAsBytes(await pdf.save());

      return compFile;
    } catch (err) {
      throw Exception(err);
    }
  }


After digging deep into the code The Error was Related to the Functions where the User gets the List of Cropped Images. If the image List gets empty, the pdf generated by this will output a corrupted document.
